# Optimizing assignment into an array from various arrays - NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, optimization, vectorization

I have four square matrices with dimension 3Nx3N, called A, B, C and D.

I want to combine them in a single matrix.
The code with *for* loops is the following:

```
import numpy
N = 3
A = numpy.random.random((3*N, 3*N))
B = numpy.random.random((3*N, 3*N))
C = numpy.random.random((3*N, 3*N))
D = numpy.random.random((3*N, 3*N))

final = numpy.zeros((6*N, 6*N))

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        for k in range(3):
            for l in range(3):
                final[6*i + k][6*j + l] = A[3*i+k][3*j+l]
                final[6*i + k + 3][6*j + l + 3] = B[3*i+k][3*j+l]
                final[6*i + k + 3][6*j + l] = C[3*i+k][3*j+l]
                final[6*i + k][6*j + l + 3] = D[3*i+k][3*j+l]
```

Is it possible to write the previous for loops in a numpythonic way?

Comment: (off-topic) | I was thinking to myself, the only time I've heard someone say "numpythonic" was some other person on SO. But then I checked and that was you too :)

Comment: @Mitch Almost a *tonic*.

Comment: Yes, I'm fighting with different ways of make for loops in a Numpythonic way. The eye is a mistake, It should be zero.

Comment: @Guillaume Jacquenot N is not 3, is any number! But now I understood, is just to be an executable code! Cool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great problem for practicing [`array-slicing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) into multi-dimensional tensors/arrays!

We will initialize the output array as a multi-dimensional `6D` array and simply slice it and assign the four arrays being reshaped as `4D` arrays. The intention is avoid any stacking/concatenating as those would be expensive specially when working with large arrays by instead working with reshaping of input arrays, which would be merely views.

Here's the implementation -

```
out = np.zeros((N,2,3,N,2,3),dtype=A.dtype)
out[:,0,:,:,0,:] = A.reshape(N,3,N,3)
out[:,0,:,:,1,:] = D.reshape(N,3,N,3)
out[:,1,:,:,0,:] = C.reshape(N,3,N,3)
out[:,1,:,:,1,:] = B.reshape(N,3,N,3)
out.shape = (6*N,6*N)
```

Just to explain a bit more, we had :

```
            |------------------------ Axes for selecting A, B, C, D
np.zeros((N,2,3,N,2,3),dtype=A.dtype)
                  |------------------------- Axes for selecting A, B, C, D
```

Thus, those two axes (second and fifth) of lengths `(2x2) = 4` were used to select between the four inputs.

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
def original_app(A, B, C, D):
    final = np.zeros((6*N,6*N),dtype=A.dtype)
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            for k in range(3):
                for l in range(3):
                    final[6*i + k][6*j + l] = A[3*i+k][3*j+l]
                    final[6*i + k + 3][6*j + l + 3] = B[3*i+k][3*j+l]
                    final[6*i + k + 3][6*j + l] = C[3*i+k][3*j+l]
                    final[6*i + k][6*j + l + 3] = D[3*i+k][3*j+l]
    return final

def slicing_app(A, B, C, D):
    out = np.zeros((N,2,3,N,2,3),dtype=A.dtype)
    out[:,0,:,:,0,:] = A.reshape(N,3,N,3)
    out[:,0,:,:,1,:] = D.reshape(N,3,N,3)
    out[:,1,:,:,0,:] = C.reshape(N,3,N,3)
    out[:,1,:,:,1,:] = B.reshape(N,3,N,3)
    return out.reshape(6*N,6*N)
```

Timings and verification -

```
In [147]: # Setup input arrays
     ...: N = 200
     ...: A = np.random.randint(11,99,(3*N,3*N))
     ...: B = np.random.randint(11,99,(3*N,3*N))
     ...: C = np.random.randint(11,99,(3*N,3*N))
     ...: D = np.random.randint(11,99,(3*N,3*N))
     ...: 

In [148]: np.allclose(slicing_app(A, B, C, D), original_app(A, B, C, D))
Out[148]: True

In [149]: %timeit original_app(A, B, C, D)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.63 s per loop

In [150]: %timeit slicing_app(A, B, C, D)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.26 ms per loop
```

Comment: The command `numpy.allclose(out, final)` returns True: this ensures that it is what we want to perform

Comment: @GuillaumeJacquenot Thanks for the confirmation! Added runtime test alongwith the verification part too.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start with a couple of generic observations

For `numpy` arrays we normally use the [ , ] syntax rather than [][]
    final[6*i + k][6*j + l]
    final[6*i + k, 6*j + l]

For new arrays built from others we often use things like reshape and slicing so that we can then add them together as blocks rather than with iterative loops

For an simple example, to take successive differences:

```
 y = x[1:] - x[:-1]
```

Regarding the title, 'matrix creation' is clearer.  'load' has more of the sense of reading data from a file, as in `np.loadtxt`.

=================

So with `N=1`,

```
In [171]: A=np.arange(0,9).reshape(3,3)
In [172]: B=np.arange(10,19).reshape(3,3)
In [173]: C=np.arange(20,29).reshape(3,3)
In [174]: D=np.arange(30,39).reshape(3,3)

In [178]: final
Out[178]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2, 30, 31, 32],
       [ 3,  4,  5, 33, 34, 35],
       [ 6,  7,  8, 36, 37, 38],
       [20, 21, 22, 10, 11, 12],
       [23, 24, 25, 13, 14, 15],
       [26, 27, 28, 16, 17, 18]])
```

Which can be created with one call to `bmat`:

```
In [183]: np.bmat([[A,D],[C,B]]).A
Out[183]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2, 30, 31, 32],
       [ 3,  4,  5, 33, 34, 35],
       [ 6,  7,  8, 36, 37, 38],
       [20, 21, 22, 10, 11, 12],
       [23, 24, 25, 13, 14, 15],
       [26, 27, 28, 16, 17, 18]])
```

`bmat` uses a mix of `hstack` and `vstack`. It also produces a `np.matrix`, hence the need for `.A`. `@Divakar's` solution is bound to be faster.

This does not match with N=3. 3x3 blocks are out of order.  But expanding the array to 6d (as Divakar does), and swapping some axes, puts the sub blocks into the the right order.

For `N=3`:

```
In [57]: block=np.bmat([[A,D],[C,B]])
In [58]: b1=block.A.reshape(2,3,3,2,3,3)
In [59]: b2=b1.transpose(1,0,2,4,3,5)
In [60]: b3=b2.reshape(18,18)
In [61]: np.allclose(b3,final)
Out[61]: True
```

In quick time tests (N=3), my approach is about half the speed of `slicing_app`.

As a matter of curiosity, `bmat` works with a string input: `np.bmat('A,D;C,B')`.  That's because `np.matrix` was trying, years ago, to give a MATLAB feel.

Answer (score 1):

you can just concat em

concat A and B horizontally
concat C and D horizontally

concat the conjunction of AB with the conjucntion of CD vertically

example:

```
AB = numpy.concatenate([A,B],1)
CD = numpy.concatenate([C,D],1)
ABCD = numpy.concatenate([AB,CD],0)
```

i hope that helps :)

Comment: The result is not the one expected: `numpy.allclose(ABCD, final)` returns false

Comment: did you try just to print ABCD? it shld be the desired matrix. you can (should) check the values manually printing the matrix to see if it corresponds to what is expected.  try with minor 2x2 matrixes as an example/test

Comment: You are on the right track.  My answer with `bmat` does this sort of `concatenate`.  But the OP's layout is more complicated, requiring some reshaping and axis swapping.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do that, using [view_as_blocks](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_blocks) :

```
from skimage.util import view_as_blocks

def by_blocks():
    final = numpy.empty((6*N,6*N))
    a,b,c,d,f= [view_as_blocks(X,(3,3)) for X in [A,B,C,D,final]]
    f[0::2,0::2]=a
    f[1::2,1::2]=b
    f[1::2,0::2]=c
    f[0::2,1::2]=d
    return final
```

You just have to think block by block, letting view_as_blocks manage strides and shapes for you. It is as fast as other numpy solutions.